# Sqlite - Remove trailing zeros in decimal

Tags: sqlite, rounding, trailing

select round(836.0) returns 836.0

How can i remove the trailing zeroes in an sqlite query.

836.00 should be 836
836.440 should be 836.44

Comment: Show the code that reads the number and displays it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `836.44` you need a decimal return type, `836` expressed in this way will always have a `.00`.  `836` on its own would need to be an integer and you cannot mix types in a column like that.

Your only option would be to use a string return type and remove `.0*`

```
select rtrim(rtrim(round(FLD, 2), '0'), '.')
```

Instead, this is best done in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

For small numbers, you can use the `%g` option of `printf()`, together with `round()`.

```
select round(25.999, 2); --- prints "26.0"

select printf("%g", round(25.999, 2)); --- prints "26"
```

Comment: what qualifies as a _small number_, and why only these can be used with printf?

Comment: I found this in the docs - The floating-point to text conversion subfunction for the built-in printf() is limited in precision to 16 significant digits or 26 significant digits if the "!" alternate-form-2 flag is used. Every IEEE-754 double can be represented exactly as a decimal floating-point value, but some doubles require more than 16 or 26 significant digits. - is that what you're referring to?